# Android view client does not show id for some screens

Tags: monkeyrunner

I m using android view client to find id using the command "java -jar androidviewclient-3.0.0.jar dump",it is showing id for some screens but on some screens thre error is "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 58-60: or inal not in range(128)" can anyone explain me what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Give the latest **AndroidviewClient** release (https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/releases/tag/v3.1.2) a try. **UTF-8** support is constantly improving.